# How do I keep whitespace in BeautifulSoup.contents

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Most examples I find online show how to remove whitespace - but in my case I need to keep it.. I have

```
html = "I can flip this whole thing with one hand\n               <span>D#m</span>\nThe ringleader man\n<span>A#</span>                           <span>Dm</span>                          <span>A#</span>\nI know~~~~ it's a fact that you'd rather just have some of me instead"
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = (unicode('').join(unicode(content) for content in bs.contents))
```

Which I expect to keep the whitespace (the "html" variable contains the contents of a pre tag) -- but it seems to replace multiple spaces with a single space.

How do I keep/get the raw contents of a given beautifulsoup parser?

Comment: `string.replace("double space","single space").strip()`??  or `normalize-space(string)` when use xpath

Comment: If you want just the raw contents of a soup-ified html input, you access them through 'bs'.  This will preserve the whitespace.

Comment: I added the "html" variable as well -- @n1c9, I tried accessing via "bs" and the additional spaces are still removed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The html parser seems to only keeps whitespace if the content you are parsing is in a <pre> tag -- in my case, the pre tag was removed. Adding

```
html = "<pre>" + html + "</pre>"
```

preserved the whitespace.