# How (not to) reformat html with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am just trying to learn to use BeautifulSoup to parse and modify html files. I wonder whether it is possible to print out an html file exactly as it was before being parsed (including empty lines, line indentation etc.) except for the elements I explicitly want to change?

**Note:** my request is not only that spaces are left unchanged; what I'm asking is that no changes are introduced *at all* in the html file, except in the specified elements.

Comment: BeautifulSoup provides a handy `prettify` method if that helps?

Comment: Quite the contrary: I want the it does not change the original file, except where it is explicitly requested

Comment: Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788047/how-do-i-keep-whitespace-in-beautifulsoup-contents)?

Comment: Adding `<pre>` does not solve my problem. This is why I don't think my question is a duplicate