# Selective parsing with BeautifulSoup (or some other Python solution)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I need to parse a html file selectively. Namely, I need to delete some elements conditional on a their class or id, while leaving the rest of the file unchanged. I tried BeautifulSoup, and followed [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788047/how-do-i-keep-whitespace-in-beautifulsoup-contents). However, including the html code within `<pre>` tags didn't really work: BeautifulSoup still introduces a number of changes in the html file (as an example, it inverts the order between `alt` and `src` within a `img`). Instead, what I need is that the rest of the file remains exactly as it is.

Here is my script (taking a html file from STDIN):

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

myfile = sys.stdin

with myfile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup("<pre>" + myfile.read() + "</pre>","lxml")

for element in soup.find_all(True,{'class':'sidenote'}):
    element.extract()

print(soup)
```

The output is similar except that there are some changes. For example, this code in the input file

```
<img src="fig/figura-06-01-b.jpg" alt="Figura 6.1b" />
```

becomes

```
<img alt="Figura 6.1b" src="fig/figura-06-01-b.jpg"/>
```

I know this is a minor modification of the file, which is irrelevant if the final destination of the file is to be published on a website. However, because I need to parse the file further (to produce tex code), this change forces me to modify other script.

My question is more general: is there a way to change only certain parts of a html file given as input?

Comment: Please provide an MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `bd4` and other html parsers break down the html document and then reconstruct it. Is the order of tag attributes so important?

Comment: Unfortunately it is in my case, because the resulting html file must be further  parsed with other scripts which have already been written and I wouldn't want to change.

Comment: Please add some sample HTML and your expected output.